# Should I clear event listeners if the reference to the object will be lost?

Tags: .net, events, reference, listeners

Is there a good reason to manually remove event listeners from object's events if the reference to the object is going to be lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. If you're looking at code which does this, it's probably because someone's read that events cause memory leaks, but not really understood why. (It's when the event *subscriber* is prevented from being collected because the event *publisher* has a reference to it. In your case, it's the *publisher* which is becoming eligible for garbage collection anyway, so that problem doesn't apply.)